# jQuery initiating a extra call to server

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a ASP.NET MVC application and on one of its page; have a button which sends a ajax request to load the data (data request goes to web api I have created) in Kendo Listview control i have on that page.
There are four kendo list views on the page and data is getting binded to them on click of the button.
How i bind data to one of the four kendo list view is like below:

```
@(Html.Kendo().ListView<CareComplete.Data.Core.ViewModel.PersonInfo>()
                      .Name("otherListView").TagName("div")
                      .ClientTemplateId("templatePerson")
                      .Pageable(page =>
                      {
                          page.Messages(mess => mess.Display(Constants.ShowingPersonPerPage + " others"));
                          page.PageSizes(AppSettings.PagingArray).Messages(mes =>
                          {
                              mes.ItemsPerPage(string.Format(Constants.PersonPerPage, "Other persons"));
                              mes.Empty(string.Format(Constants.NoPersonFound, "Other person"));
                          });
                          page.ButtonCount(AppSettings.PagingOptionCount);
                      })
                      .DataSource(dataSource =>
                      {
                          dataSource.Read((read => read.Url(personInfoUrl).Type(HttpVerbs.Get).Data("otherDataFilter")));
                          dataSource.PageSize(AppSettings.DefaultPageSize);

                      }).Events(events => events.DataBound("onOtherDataChange"))
                      .AutoBind(false)//not to load list automatically
            )``
```

In Addition to four data bind request two more requests are going to server whenever I am clicking that button which is evident in browser developer tools "Network".

http://test.com:54785/null

http://test.com:54785/undefined

For quick reference attached is the screen shot of browser developer tools.

I can see it is originating from jquery-2.1.1.js file; but could not find what is the problem.

Can someone help me on this?

Thanks,

Comment: Do you have something like image references with empty src?

Comment: No i do not have any image reference with empty src @ fly_ua